# Android Spinner databind using array list

Tags: android, data-binding, arraylist, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I have a array list like this:

```
private ArrayList<Locations> Artist_Result = new ArrayList<Location>();
```

This Location class has two properties: `id` and `location`.

I need to bind my `ArrayList` to a spinner. I have tried it this way:

```
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerSpcial);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Artist_Result);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

However, it shows the object's hexadecimal value. So I think I have to set display the text and value for that spinner controller.

Comment: As a trivial quick and dirty solution you could simply implement `toString()` in `Locations`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `ArrayAdapter` tries to display your `Location`-objects as strings (which causes the Hex-values), by calling the [`Object.toString()`-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). It's default implementation returns:

> [...] a string consisting of **the name of the class** of which the object
>   is an instance, **the at-sign character** `@', and the unsigned
>   **hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.**

To make the `ArrayAdadpter` show something actually useful in the item list, you can override the `toString()`-method to return something meaningful:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return "Something meaningful here...";
}
```

---

**Another way to do this is**, to extend [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) **and** implement [SpinnerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) to create your own Adapter, which knows that the elements in your `ArrayList` are objects and how to use the properties of those objects.

### [Revised] Implementation Example

I was playing around a bit and I managed to get something to work:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Create and display a Spinner:
        Spinner s = new Spinner(this);
        AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        this.setContentView(s, params);
        // fill the ArrayList:
        List<Guy> guys = new ArrayList<Guy>();
        guys.add(new Guy("Lukas", 18));
        guys.add(new Guy("Steve", 20));
        guys.add(new Guy("Forest", 50));
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(guys);
        // apply the Adapter:
        s.setAdapter(adapter);
        // onClickListener:
        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            /**
             * Called when a new item was selected (in the Spinner)
             */
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                       View view, int pos, long id) {
                Guy g = (Guy) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        g.getName()+" is "+g.getAge()+" years old.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * This is your own Adapter implementation which displays
     * the ArrayList of "Guy"-Objects.
     */
    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

        /**
         * The internal data (the ArrayList with the Objects).
         */
        private final List<Guy> data;

        public MyAdapter(List<Guy> data){
            this.data = data;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the Size of the ArrayList
         */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        /**
         * Returns one Element of the ArrayList
         * at the specified position.
         */
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return data.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }
        /**
         * Returns the View that is shown when a element was
         * selected.
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View recycle, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView text;
            if (recycle != null){
                // Re-use the recycled view here!
                text = (TextView) recycle;
            } else {
                // No recycled view, inflate the "original" from the platform:
                text = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false
                );
            }
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            text.setText(data.get(position).name);
            return text;
        }


    }

    /**
     * A simple class which holds some information-fields
     * about some Guys.
     */
    private class Guy{
        private final String name;
        private final int age;

        public Guy(String name, int age){
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }
    }
}
```

I fully commented the code, if you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask them.

Comment: I'm new to Android application development. So if you can give me some sample code for your given solution I appreciate that.Thanks Lukas Knuth.

Comment: Thank you very much Lukas Knuth your example works fine. Thanks :)))))

Comment: the "getViewTypeCount" method is handled incorrectly. For this type of adpater it should return 1. Adapters try to recycle views and if they know that there are more than 1 views it may not recycle them optimally. Read JavaDoc for the method.

Comment: this is really nice, but the only thing that bugs me is 
  `@Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position)
  {
   return android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;
  }`
  does not work.

Comment: How to set selected by age item

Answer (score 8):

## Simplest Solution

After scouring different solutions on SO, I found the following to be the simplest and cleanest solution for populating a `Spinner` with custom `Objects`. Here's the full implementation:

#### Location.java

```
public class Location{
    public int id;
    public String location;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.location;            // What to display in the Spinner list.
    }
}
```

#### res/layout/spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

#### res/layout/your_activity_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/location" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### In Your Activity

```
// In this case, it's a List of Locations, but it can be a List of anything.
List<Location> locations = Location.all();                  

ArrayAdapter locationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner, locations);

Spinner locationSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location);
locationSpinner.setAdapter(locationAdapter);



// And to get the actual Location object that was selected, you can do this.
Location location = (Location) ( (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location) ).getSelectedItem();
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Lukas' answer above (below?) I was able to get started on this, but my problem was that his implementation of the `getDropDownView` made the dropdown items just a plain text - so no padding and no nice green radio button like you get when using the `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`.

So as above, except the `getDropDownView` method would be:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
  if (convertView == null)
  {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
  }

  TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
  textView.setText(items.get(position).getName());

  return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been searching for this for way too long now.

Answer (score 3):

**Well, am not gonna confuse with more details.**

Just create your **`ArrayList`** and bind your values like this.

```
ArrayList tExp = new ArrayList();
for(int i=1;i<=50;i++)
{
    tExp.add(i);
}
```

Assuming that you have already a spinner control on your layout say with id, `spinner1`. Add this code below.

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tExp);
adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp.setAdapter(adp1);
```

All the above code goes under your `onCreate` function.

Answer (score 2):

Thank Lukas, you help me a lot.
I d'like to improve your answer.
If you just want to access the selected item later, you can use this :

```
Spinner spn   = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
Guy     oGuy  = (Guy)     spn.getSelectedItem();
```

So you don't have to use the setOnItemSelectedListener() in your initialisation :)