# Android spinner background and default text

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a spinner to my android application that looks like that one in the image.

I don't want the selector to appear and I want a default text to appear on the left. I was thinking that I can put a background image that will contain the text, but I'm afraid that it won't be centered with the option that I will choose.

I've created functionality but with design I have big problems.

[spinner -exemple http://www.media-sun.ro/spinner_exempla.jpg](http://www.media-sun.ro/spinner_exempla.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create my own data-adapter for the `Spinner` by creating a new class which implements the [SpinnerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html)-interface (an example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562236/android-spinner-databind-using-array-list/6562433#6562433)).

In your own Adapter, you can then modify the displayed Text (for example in the `getView`-method) and make it print out your "Option Name", too.